# Small trouble with variable referencing in StringReplace?

Tags: string-manipulation, regular-expressions

I am trying to do the following:

Take a string `abcdEFGpcf` and replace whatever is between `abcd` and `pcf` by something that depends on `EFG`, for example by `EFGH` and then obtain `abcdEFGHpcf`. I am trying to use regex for this but I'm extremely confused by the notation.

I guess it's also possible to do this with string patterns but I am also confused by the notation. I know how to replace a fixed substring by something else, but in this case we need to reference $x=$ `EFG` and put it in the new expression.

Comment: Do you mean something like: `StringReplace["abcdEFGpcf", 
 "abcd" ~~ x__ ~~ "pcf" :> "abcd" ~~ ToLowerCase[x] ~~ "pcf"]` ?

Comment: @Domen Quite there. I was looking for `StringReplace["abcdEFGpcf", 
 "abcd" ~~ x__ ~~ "pcf" :> "abcd" ~~ x ~~ "H" ~~ "pcf"]`  but your code helped me a lot. And I guess now I solved this doubt and all further doubts I had. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

Let's put your transformation into a function for re-usability:

```
func[str_] := str <> "H"
```

Here's your input:

```
input = "abcdEFGpcf"
```

Now, we can use either string expressions or `RegularExpression`:

```
StringReplace[input, head : "abcd" ~~ mid___ ~~ tail : "pcf" :> head <> func[mid] <> tail]
```

`"abcdEFGHpcf"`

In the above, I named the two constant patterns to avoid repeating them in the rule.

```
StringReplace[input, RegularExpression["(abcd)(.*)(pcf)"] -> "$1" <> func["$2"] <> "$3"]
```

`"abcdEFGHpcf"`

In this case, we don't need to explicitly name the patterns, because we can use `$n` on the right hand side to reference a captured substring.

Answer (score 4):

You could also just use `StringReplacePart`, no need for patterns !

```
s = "abcdYYYYpcfabcdXXXXpcf"
a = "abcd"
b = "pcf"
rep = "EFGH"
```

In the above `s` is your string. `a` and `b` are the first and last terminal strings, and you want to replace everything in between them with `rep`. Right? Then

```
p1 = StringPosition[s, a]
p2 = StringPosition[s, b]
m = MapThread[{#1[[2]] + 1, #2[[1]] - 1} &, {p1, p2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above gives the positions within `s` with each starting and ending terminal strings are located. Now use

```
StringReplacePart[s, rep, m]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

ps. I see now you want replacement to happen only if string inside these terminal strings depends "EFG". The above code can be modified to do that, by adding a check inside the `MapThread` to only pick these positions if the inner string satisfies this conditions.

**This version** only does the replacement if the inner string contains "EFG"

```
repl[s_String,from_,to_,lookfor_]:=If[StringContainsQ[StringTake[s,{from,to}],lookfor],{from,to},Nothing];
replaceSubStrings[s_String,fromS_String,toS_String,replS_String,lookFor_String]:=Module[{p1,p2,m,result=s},
    p1=StringPosition[s,fromS];
    p2=StringPosition[s,toS];
    If[Length[p1]>0&&Length[p1]>0,
       m=MapThread[repl[s,#1[[2]]+1,#2[[1]]-1,lookFor]&,{p1,p2}];
       If[Length[m]>0,
          result = StringReplacePart[s,replS,m]
       ]
    ];
    
    result
]
```

Example use:

```
replaceSubStrings["abcdEFGpcfabcdXXXXpcf", "abcd", "pcf", "EFGH", "EFG"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
replaceSubStrings["abcdEFGpcfabcdXXXXpcfnnnnnabcdEFGzzzzzzpcf","abcd","pcf","EFGH","EFG"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 replaceSubStrings["abcdxxxpcf", "abcd", "pcf", "EFGH", "EFG"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]